# Padding exception in java 7:Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, des, badpaddingexception

Hi I am using tripedes key to read from input stream and write to output stream.
Getting this execption in java7/8:Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

```
byte[] passwd = Base64Util.decode(pwd);
bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(passwd);
baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
// Read bytes, decrypt, and write them out.
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = bais.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, bytesRead));
}
// Write out the final bunch of decrypted bytes
out.write(cipher.doFinal());
out.flush();
```

Can anyone please tell me what might be error in cipher.doFinal?

Update, encryption code copied from comment:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

// Create a special output stream to do the work for us
CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);

// Read from the input and write to the encrypting output stream
byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
int bytesRead;
while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    cos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
cos.close();
```

Comment: Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    // Create a special output stream to do the work for us
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(out, cipher);

    // Read from the input and write to the encrypting output stream
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      cos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    cos.close();

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. You should [edit] your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the input data is not always a multiple of the block size then padding must be added to the input data; specify padding, PKCS#5 is the preferred padding for DES/3DES.

The `getInstance` call is not fully specified, missing are the mode and padding options. Add the full specification such as: "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding (168)". See [Class Cipher documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html).

Do not use 3DES in new code, it is insecure and also do not use ECB mode, it too is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: still getting same error after doing "DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding"

Comment: Make sure that `passed` and `key` are the same, a hex dump is the best way.

Comment: I didnt understand what passed and key i need to check

Comment: Right, not `passed`, just the `key` for both encryption and decryption.